# Django MongoDB problem

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

my django app run with mysql, but when i try with mongodb then show thie error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 209, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 106, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 191, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 180, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 157, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/db/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/home/abdullah/django-trunk/django/db/utils.py", line 82, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_mongodb_engine-0.4.0-py2.6.egg/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.ops = DatabaseOperations(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/djangotoolbox-0.9.2-py2.6.egg/djangotoolbox/db/base.py", line 28, in __init__
    super(NonrelDatabaseOperations, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

** I have installed all necessary module installed, but when i want to runserver then show this message

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My best guess so far is that it has something to do with incompatible versions of django-mongodb and djangotoolbox - anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 9):

I managed to fix the same error by using these packages on github:

```
https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel
https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
```

instead of the ones recommended on Django-Mongodb's setup page. Also, make sure to use the `master` branch of each, so as to not run into compatibility problems. If you're using `pip`, you can either `pip install` each of the following lines separately, or put them into your version of a `requirements.txt` file for your project:

```
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel@master
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox@master
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine@master
```

And then run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: @Burak Things might have changed since I posted this, but it seems to have solved the problem for a number of people. Maybe just check that you uninstalled the original versions first, before installing the new ones, and that you're not accidentally still running the broken version from pip.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I will try again.